# WCF REST - Passing multiple parameters via URL

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetInstantDebitResponse/{param}")]
    string GetInstantDebitResponse(string param);
}
```

I'm new to this so pardon me for not writing technically. I'm using the above function to call a function **GetInstantDebitResponse(string param)**. So for that, in the URL, I'm calling **http://localhost:45678/Service1.svc/GetInstantDebitResponse/abc**.

What change I should make if I have to call a URL like below:
**http://localhost:45678/Service1.svc/GetInstantDebitResponse?param1=abc&param2=def&param3=ghi**

Comment: `GetInstantDebitResponse(string param, string param2, string param3)` and `UriTemplate = "GetInstantDebitResponse/{param}/{param2}/{param3}`

Comment: Have you tried just add additional parameter in the function?

Comment: When I used this URL (http://localhost:45678/Service1.svc/GetInstantDebitResponse?param=abc), its showing an error - Endpoint not found.

Comment: Look at your [UriTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) this is where you format your url. Try to change `/{param}` to `/param={param}`

Comment: @Reniuz Worked when I used '?' instead of '/' after GetInstantDebitResponse in the UriTemplate. ie, _UriTemplate = "GetInstantDebitResponse?param1={param1}&param2={param2}&param3={param3}"_

Comment: Currently working on another problem. one of my parameter is '**+**'. After passing it through URL (_&param3=+_), i'm getting only a space (" ") in the function.

Comment: Whenever you want use query with '?' or '/'. + is special reserved char, [encode to use it in query](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). I suggest to read more about url queries.